# Cannot Invert a matrix in R using solve() or ginv()

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, matrix-inverse

#### tl/dr

Does anyone know a function or routine which allows to solve linear systems using a tikhonov regularization? More generally, a function or routine to correctly solve linear systems, whether well or ill conditioned?

#### Details

I have big problems to find a correct inverse matrix using R standard functions solve and ginv. I do not understand why solve or ginv cannot correctly invert some matrices. For example, inverting the following matrix $X$ $(4 \times 4)$:

```
[r1] 112    114.02675   -99.0725    48.21424
[r2] 114.02675  116.09108   -100.91021  49.01754
[r3] -99.0725   -100.91021  89.97304    -39.267
[r4] 48.21424   49.01754    -39.267         26.11804
```

gives this curious result $X^{-1}$ :

```
[r1]  7581993.46   -7459378.79  -46534.6234 -66885.6052
[r2] -7459378.79   7338753.44   45787.7223  65800.3842
[r3] -46534.62     45787.72 290.6085    407.4297
[r4]  66885.61     65800.38 407.4297    592.1243
```

MS Excel provides this one which is correct :

```
[r1] 290607.5736   -285895.9835 -1773.086548    -2570.2266
[r2] -285895.9835  281267.2032  1749.988341 2524.997062
[r3] -1773.086548  1749.988341  15.81951395 12.59978592
[r4] -2570.2266    2524.997062  12.59978592 24.81554691
```

I know that this is the correct solution because $XX^{-1}$ gives the Identity matrix (not with the inverse matrix calculated with solve or ginv).

1. Does anyone have an explanation?
2. How can I calculate correct inverse matrices in `R`?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please tell us the reciprocal condition number of your matrix? In R, for a matrix `A`, this is given by `rcond(A)`.

Comment: @Zen, I've computed it as `4.531075e-09`

Comment: @Lio, when I enter this matrix (into a variable `x`) and calculate `solve(x) %*% x` I got something pretty darn close to the identity (errors are $<10^{-8})$. Why is that different from what you're seeing?

Comment: Perform an SVD of $X$: the largest three eigenvalues are 337, 7.5, and .01; the last is 0.0000017: even for double-precision floating arithmetic, $X$ has to be considered essentially singular and therefore does not have an inverse.  Attempts to invert it can be unstable (to put it mildly). Excel apparently uses a good stable inversion routine, but even its output is correct only to eight to nine decimal places rather than the 16 available in double precision: effectively it has already lost seven to eight decimal places of precision.

Comment: See if evaluating $(A + \epsilon I)^{-1}$, for small $\epsilon$, instead of $A^{-1}$, gives a sensible answer to your problem.

Comment: Search the Internet for "Tikhonov regularization" and "ridge regression".

Comment: @Macro  
"when I enter this matrix (into a variable x) and calculate solve(x) %*% x I got something pretty darn close to the identity (errors are <10−8). Why is that different from what you're seeing?" I know it: solve(x) %*% x gives I but curiously solve(x) alone is not correct!?! Thanks

Comment: @whuber I think you are right but how can I fix this problem? Excel does, why not R?

Comment: Lio, I suspect--but have not checked--that procedures like Excel's and R's `solve` (as indicated by @Macro's [comment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30472/cannot-invert-a-matrix-in-r-using-solve-or-ginv#comment58609_30472)) may be much more robust to floating point error than certain others such as the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse. If Excel had an M-P procedure, it would likely have the same problem. So you need to be selective and choose appropriate solution methods depending on the characteristics of the input matrix.

Comment: Note, too, that `MASS::ginv` does a very rough calculation by default. See what you get when you compute `MASS::ginv(x, tol=10^-12)` :-).

Comment: whuber, I don't know if Excel has a MP procedure but it works and ginv doesn't. I also try with the function mpinv <- function(X, eps = 1e-13){ #moore penrose inverse matrix (GINV)
s <- svd(X)
e <- s$d
e[e > eps] <- 1/e[e > eps]
return(s$v %*% diag(e) %*% t(s$u))
} increasing/decreasing eps does not solve this problem.

Comment: whuber, my input matrix changes at each iteration of an optimization process launched by optim(). So, I need a robust method to handle all cases correctly.

Comment: Lio, ginv *does* work: please read my preceding comment. The difference between Excel and R is that R gives the knowledgeable user control over the algorithms so they can be applied appropriately. But, as with all numerical calculations, *caveat calculator*!

Comment: whuber, maybe it works for this particular matrix but within a function to optimize (using optim) ginv fails to give a correct solution. Does anyone know a function or routine which allows to solve linear systems using a tikhonov regularization? More generally, a function or routine to correctly solve linear systems, whether well or ill conditioned? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question. Let me share some information:

I use Microsoft R open v. 4.0.
Take a look at my results:

```
> a = c(112,    114.02675,   -99.0725,    48.21424,
+ 114.02675,  116.09108,   -100.91021,  49.01754,
+ -99.0725,   -100.91021,  89.97304,    -39.267,
+ 48.21424,   49.01754,    -39.267,         26.11804)
> 
> matA = matrix(a, ncol=4)
> matA
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 112.00000  114.02675  -99.07250  48.21424
[2,] 114.02675  116.09108 -100.91021  49.01754
[3,] -99.07250 -100.91021   89.97304 -39.26700
[4,]  48.21424   49.01754  -39.26700  26.11804
> 
> solve(matA)
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  290607.572 -285895.982 -1773.08654 -2570.22659
[2,] -285895.982  281267.202  1749.98833  2524.99705
[3,]   -1773.087    1749.988    15.81951    12.59979
[4,]   -2570.227    2524.997    12.59979    24.81555
```